# What Lovecraft inspired classes exist?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Are there any classes that resemble an occultist of the Lovecraftian mythos, or have such a feeling, except the alienist and the flesh warper? The aberration blood feats are interesting but just give flavor; I am searching for something more solid, a base or prestige class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Lovecraftian feel is broader then most people think: You could easily have NPCs with the Dread Pirate PrC involved in your version of The Shadow Over Innsmouth. I also based this on what I could see appearing in Lovecraft's stories, rather then just Mythos type creatures (Thus degenerate humans and such are also fair game, as are charismatic cult leader types, etc). Howard, a good friend of Lovecraft's, also published stories in the same vein, but a bit more hack and slash. I've denoted classes that would work well with his books.

The other idea is to take rules from a class, then rewrite the theme and feeling of it to be more lovecraftian: Example: Bear Warrior instead is embracing his Shoggoth heritage, and becomes more and more unnatural as he goes up in levels.

However here are some which I could think would be useful or lend themselves to Lovecraftian work:

Complete Adventurer:

- Animal Lord (Sharklord, Apelord [Degenerate humans])
- Master of Many Forms (Change into Ooze and Abberations)
- Ghostfaced Killer (More Howardian horror, but it goes well with Lovecraftian horror)

Complete Arcane:

- Acolyte of the Skin
- **Alienist**
- Blood Magus
- Effigy Master (With horrible enough effigies)
- Master Transmogrifist (Transformation is a running Lovecraftian theme)

Complete Divine

- Black Flame Zelot (With some re-themeing, but evil assassins would tie in well with say, The Red Hook Horror)
- Blighter
- Entropomancer
- Evangilist (For evil priests)
- Geomancer (Drift mutates you in similar ways to The Innsmouth Look)

Complete Mage

- Nightmare Spinner
- Wild Soul (If given a darker slant, change the creatures to look more horrific, while using the same stats)

Complete Warrior

- Bear Warrior (Except replace bear with deep one, shoggoth, something)
- Eye Of Grumpsh (Cultist, replace Grumpsh with something mythos) [More Robert E. Howard than Lovecraft, but he was a good friend of Lovecrafts and wrote some very Mythos-y stories, check out the collection Black Caan for examples.]
- Ravager [Howard]

Drow of the Underdark (Based only on names)

- Arachnomancer
- Demonbinder
- Insidious Corruptor

Heroes of Horror (names again), most of them

- Fiend-Blooded
- **Tainted Scholar**
- Dread Witch
- Corrupt Avenger
- **Archivist**

Libris Mortis: Pretty much all of them

Lords of Madness:  Pretty much all of them

Magic of Incarnum: All of the ones that involve merging Incarum into yourself.

Tome of Magic: All of them, binding dead shades to serve you. Particularly the **binder**.

Eberron Campaign Setting
 - Master Inquisitive (for investigators)

Races of Eberron

- Quori Nightmare
- Anything with Quori really

Champions of Ruin

- Black Blood Cultist (Degenerate humans, common in Lovecraft)
- Night Mask Deathbringer (Unable to function in sun, evil killers? Fiddle with the falavour a bit and make them degenerate)

Player's Guide to Faerûn

- Slime Lord

Serpent Kingdoms: Pretty much all of them

Comment: There are a lot more if you go to 3.0; There was so stuff that would work quite well with a bit of good DMing. Master of Chains for example.

Comment: Is there a particular reason my answer is getting downvoted? I thought I put quite a lot of work into it, and while I realize a lot of my selections are selective I didn't think people would dislike it that much.

Comment: I didn’t downvote (I actually upvoted), but I think a number of these are stretches, and the length hides the better ones. Particularly the alienist from *Complete Arcane*, the archivist from *Heroes of Horror* (which you neglect to mention) and the binder from *Tome of Magic* (which is only mentioned under “all of them” for *Tome of Magic*, but the shadowcaster and truenamer fit Lovecraft far less well though they can of course work). Also, the one class you actually bold, the tainted scholar, is **hideously** broken and should not be allowed in any campaign for any reason whatsoever.

Comment: @KRyan Hah, I put this up over a year ago, I just round it again recently and noticed a bunch of spelling errors. I've actually read very few of these, I just was annoyed there wasn't a comprehensive answer, so read class summaries of all of them and made a full list. I'll bold some of the others as well, based on your suggestions.

Comment: @KRyan But yeah, it was one downvote a year ago, just the very first one I got. Let me know what you think of the changes. I admit, I'm a compleationist and like some of the more obscure of Lovecrafts works to his straight up Cthulhu stuff, so that could make my choices look a bit odd.

Comment: I would argue that a different organization scheme would be better: rather than by book, maybe group them by how closely they fit, with categories like “Wizards explicitly intended these to be Lovecraftian” (alienist, archivist, binder, fleshwarper, others I’m sure), “These are easy to use that way” (acolyte of the skin, dread witch, nightmare spinner, etc.), and “these work with some refluffing” (which you’ve noted in parentheticals). Or groupings like “cultists/priests,” “occult researchers,” “degenerate or monstrous people,” and so on.

Comment: @KRyan In one way, yes, but if I'm looking for classes in books I already own, or in books my DM allows, then this is far more useful.

Comment: I’m not suggesting that you lose the information (parentheticals work nicely), just that things are reorganized. As is, it’s difficult to tell at a glance which ones are particularly suited or what sort of Lovecraft their suited for.

Comment: I would have thought the Oozemaster would have made the list.

Comment: @user30200 Good call. Looks like I didn't look at Masters of the Wild at all. Might not have been out yet? Or I just didn't think to look in it for Lovecraftian things.

Comment: @user30200 Looked it up: I only listed 3.5 PrCs, Oozemaster was 3.0.

Comment: My bad, I'm still getting used to the tag system here. Also, that we all play 3.x, not just 3.0 or 3.5 throws me off sometimes. Apologies.

Comment: @user30200 No worries. If you want 3.0 PrCs (or Pathfinder), make a new question and I can make another list easily enough.

Answer (score 8):

Of course, the Alienist class from Complete Arcane is specifically designed to be Lovecraftian in nature. They summon [pseudonatural creatures](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/monsters/pseudonaturalCreature.htm). The D&D 3.5e version isn't OGL but [here's a Pathfinder conversion](http://www.pathfinderdb.com/character-options/prestige-classes/779-alienist) that gets the general idea across. There are similar ideas in Gates of Firestorm Peak and the 3.0 Manual of the Planes, and the 2.0 Illithiad.

Answer (score 5):

I'm also currently at a loss for classes that are directly inspired, but there are some things that could work well with a little reflavoring.

- **Pretty much any psionic class.** The connection "Far Realm - Cthulhu Mythos" isn't that far fetched (*cough* Illithids *cough*) and many aberrations that originate from the Far Realm have psionic abilities. Especially [wilders](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/classes/wilder.htm) could work well with their limited but rather powerful and volatile abilities.
- **The generic Spellcaster class.** This one works best for NPCs, since the [variant generic classes](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/genericClasses.htm) are a bit weaker than the normal PC classes. However, since the flavor of the spellcaster class is completely open it could easily be molded into a cult ritualist or somesuch, especially since the spellcaster can learn spells (like a sorcerer) from the cleric, druid and wizard lists.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there are any others to be honest. The closest you will get is the Lords of Madness supplemental book.

Comment: Care to exlpain that downvote?

Comment: I think whoever downvoted found your 'It doesn't exist post' unhelpful. But I disagree!

Comment: It's true, though, as I'm sure you'll agree. Nothing close to Lovecraftian Mythos exists outside the Lords of Madness sourcebook, and I invite anyone to prove me wrong. (excluding published adventures and Dungeon or Dragon magazine)

Comment: The alienist is close to the Cthulhu mythos, summoning pseudonatural creatures and having a pseudonatural familiar, and he is in complete arcane. I don't know who downvoted though.

Comment: There have been several lovecraftian things posted to the WotC website over the years, as well as Kobold Quarterly.